# How do i select current program from this table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select current program (which is happening now) from this table. Please help Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `programs` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `p_day` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `program` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `p_start` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
 `p_end` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT program FROM programs 
WHERE CURDATE() = p_day 
  AND CURTIME() BETWEEN p_start AND p_end;
```

I'm making an assumption that your p_day is a valid date string, e.g. '2011-08-15' but it's not clear from your question.  Why didn't you use a DATE datatype for the p_day?

Comment: what about nex program ? SELECT program FROM programs 
WHERE CURDATE() = p_day 
  AND CURTIME() BETWEEN p_start AND p_end + 1; doesn't seems to work